# zk ajax framework vs JBoss Seam

Tags: jboss, seam, zk

I am planning to learn a new Java framework for developing enterprise applications in a much easier way. I have heard of ZK ajax framework and Jboss Seam.

It seems that ZK is mainly used for front end purposes while JBoss is for the real server stuff.

Please could someone advise me on which is better and why OR whether the two belong to different realms and therefore should not be compared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ZK is a RIA framework so that is covering the frontend. JBoss Seam is a framework which handles the persistence layer as well as the frontend. Seam happens to be maintained by the group that supports JBoss, that is where the name Jboss Seam comes from.

It seems you are confusing it with JBoss the application server. JBoss is comparable with Glassfish and others. So in principle JBoss Seam can run on Glassfish as well.

By the way as far as I know you can use ZK together with JBoss Seam. Seam gives you many options for the front end implementations.

Comparison is not really possible, but integration is!

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your answer. If JBoss seam handles the frontend just like ZK does, could you please tell me the advantage of integrating them